# how to write unit test for directives

Tags: angular, unit-testing

I have createSpinner() method and I want to write a unit test case for it

```
import {
  ComponentFactory, ComponentFactoryResolver, ComponentRef,
  Directive, ElementRef,
  Input,
  OnChanges, Renderer2, SimpleChanges, ViewContainerRef
} from '@angular/core';
import { SpinnerComponent } from "@app/shared/components/spinner/spinner.component";

@Directive({
  selector: 'button[appLoading]',
})
export class ButtonLoadingDirective implements OnChanges {
  @Input() appLoading: boolean | null = false;
  @Input() spinnerColor: string;

  private spinnerFactory: ComponentFactory<SpinnerComponent>;
  private spinner: ComponentRef<SpinnerComponent> | null = null;

  constructor(
    private elem: ElementRef,
    public viewContainerRef: ViewContainerRef,
    private componentFactoryResolver: ComponentFactoryResolver,
    private renderer: Renderer2
  ) {
    this.spinnerFactory = this.componentFactoryResolver.resolveComponentFactory(SpinnerComponent);
  }

 private createSpinner(): void {
    if (!this.spinner) {
      this.spinner = this.viewContainerRef.createComponent(this.spinnerFactory);
      if (this.spinnerColor) {
        this.spinner.instance.color = this.spinnerColor;
      }
      this.renderer.appendChild(this.elem.nativeElement, this.spinner.instance._elementRef.nativeElement);
    }
  }
```

My company gave me the task to write a test case but I don't know how to write a test case for this If condition test case, also I read many articles but not work for me. this method is written under the directives file & this method is used for the spinner so help me
`

```
import { ComponentFixture, inject, TestBed } from '@angular/core/testing';

import { ButtonLoadingDirective } from './button-loading.directive';
import { RouterTestingModule } from "@angular/router/testing";
import { HttpClientTestingModule } from "@angular/common/http/testing";
import { TranslateLoader, TranslateModule } from "@ngx-translate/core";
import { HttpLoaderFactory } from "@app/core/core-translation.module";
import { HttpClient } from "@angular/common/http";
import { SharedModule } from "@app/shared/shared.module";

fdescribe('ButtonLoadingDirective', () => {
  let component: ButtonLoadingDirective;
  let fixture: ComponentFixture<ButtonLoadingDirective>;

  beforeEach(async () => {
    await TestBed.configureTestingModule({
      declarations: [ ButtonLoadingDirective ],
      imports: [
        RouterTestingModule,
        HttpClientTestingModule,
        TranslateModule.forRoot({
          loader: {
            provide: TranslateLoader,
            useFactory: HttpLoaderFactory,
            deps: [HttpClient],
          },
        }),
        SharedModule
      ],
    })
    .compileComponents();
  });

  beforeEach(() => {
    fixture = TestBed.createComponent(ButtonLoadingDirective);
    component = fixture.componentInstance;
    fixture.detectChanges();
  });

  it('should create', () => {
    expect(component).toBeTruthy();
  });

  it('should show mark down file is false', () => {
    component[`createSpinner`]()
    expect(component[`createSpinner`]()).toEqual('');  
  });

})
```

Answer (score 1):

I think one of the best way to test Angular directives is to use a `HostComponent` like in here :
https://angular.io/guide/testing-components-scenarios#component-inside-a-test-host

You create a fake component and use its internal variables to work on the directive behavior. You will have to play with the `fixture.detectChanges` quite often. Check this also :

https://testing-angular.com/testing-directives/

```js
describe('ThresholdWarningDirective', () => {
  let fixture: ComponentFixture<HostComponent>;

  beforeEach(async () => {
    await TestBed.configureTestingModule({
      declarations: [ThresholdWarningDirective, HostComponent],
    }).compileComponents();

    fixture = TestBed.createComponent(HostComponent);
    fixture.detectChanges();
  });

  /* … */
});
```